# To prove $o(HK) = o(H)o(K)/o(H\cap K)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, self-learning

> Given that $H$ and $K$ are finite subgroups of $G$ of order $o(H)$ and $o(K)$,
>   prove that
>    $$o(HK) = \frac{o(H)\,o(K)}{o(H\cap K)}$$

I have proved for specific case when $H$ and $K$ have only $e$ in common, but how do I prove the general case? Hints?

Comment: See also [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/168942/order-of-a-product-of-subgroups) and other posts [linked there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/168942).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every element of $HK$ is of the form $hk$, where $h\in H$ and $k\in K$; further, there are $o(H) o(K)$ such representations. However, these representations are not necessarily unique. If $hk = h'k'$ for some $h,h'\in H$ and $k,k'\in K$, then $(h')^{-1}h = k'k^{-1}$. Since $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, $(h')^{-1}h\in H$; since $K$ is a subgroup of $G$, $k'k^{-1}\in K$. Therefore, if $x = (h')^{-1}h = k'k^{-1} $, then $x \in H\cap K$, $h = h'x$ and $k' = xk$. It follows that the number of repetitions of given element $hk \in HK$ is $o(H\cap K)$. Thus $o(HK)o(H\cap K) = o(H)o(K)$, or $o(HK) = o(H)o(K)/o(H\cap K)$.

Comment: if  $ hk=h'k'$ then how is $h(h')^{-1}$=$k'k^{-1}$ ?

Comment: I had a typo which I will fix. Right-multiply by $k^{-1}$ to get $h = h'k'k^{-1}$. Then left-multiply by $(h')^{-1}$ to get $(h')^{-1}h = k'k^{-1}$.

Comment: i havenot understood second last line of proof

Comment: no i mean you have written h=h'x and k'=xk .it follows that .... how do it follow?

Comment: There are $o(H\cap K)$ choices for $x$. So there are $o(H\cap K)$ ways to represent $hk$.

Comment: I think there needs to be an edit. k $\in$ K right? In the first line?

Comment: @Anonymous correct. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** $$HK=\bigcup_{h\in H}hK$$

So this set is union of some of left cosets of $K$. You need to count the number of different ones. Try to observe when they are same,

$$h_1K=h_2K\ ?$$