# Why is it true that $|AB:A|=|B:A\cap B|$ even if $A$ is not normal in $AB$? (Second Isomorphism Theorem)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

I just read about the First and Second Isomorphism Theorems in the book *Abstract Algebra* by Dummit and Foote. After proving the Second Isomorphism Theorem, they said:

> [image]

Proposition 13 isn't really important for my question (I guess) but anyway it is the one that states that if $H$ and $K$ are two finite subgroups of $G$ then $|HK|=\dfrac{|H||K|}{|H\cap K|}$.

I didn't understand why $|AB:A|=|B:A\cap B|$. It is obvious if $AB$ is finite because using the Second Isomorphism theorem we have $|AB:B|=|A:A\cap B|$ because $AB/ B \cong A/ A\cap B$. Then
$$
|AB:B|=\dfrac{|AB|}{|B|}\quad\textsf{and}\quad|A:A\cap B|=\dfrac{|A|}{|A\cap B|}\\[0.3in]
\implies\dfrac{|AB|}{|B|}=\dfrac{|A|}{|A\cap B|}\\[0.3in]
\implies\dfrac{|AB|}{|A|}=\dfrac{|B|}{|A\cap B|}
$$
which proves that $|AB:A|=|B:A\cap B|$, but this doesn't prove it if $A$ or $B$ is infinite and I believe there's a simple general proof that under the asssumptions in **Theorem 18** we get $|AB:A|=|B:A\cap B|$. Could anyone please help me? If the proof is easy (and I guess so because they stated the relation in the book like if it was obvious) then could you give me hints?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Another related post can be found [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/168942/order-of-a-product-of-subgroups).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How do we usually prove the second isomorphism theorem? We compose two homomorphisms
$$A\xrightarrow{\large\;\;\text{inclusion}\;\;}AB\xrightarrow{\large\;\;\text{quotient}\;\;}AB/B$$
observe that the composite homomorphism is surjective with kernel $A\cap B\trianglelefteq A$, and then apply the first isomorphism theorem for groups to conclude that $A/A\cap B\cong AB/B$.

What can we do when our quotients are not groups (i.e., the relevant subgroups aren't normal)? We can still apply the first isomorphism theorem for **sets** to the **function** gotten by composing
$$B\xrightarrow{\large\;\;\text{inclusion}\;\;}AB\xrightarrow{\large\;\;\text{send }x\,\mapsto\, xA\;\;}AB/A$$
and observe that two elements of $B$ are sent to the same place in $AB/A$ if and only if they differ by an element of $A\cap B$. Since the composite map is also surjective, the first isomorphism theorem for **sets** tells us there is a **bijection**
$$B/A\cap B\cong AB/A$$
and hence $|AB:A|=|B:A\cap B|$.

---

What is the "first isomorphism theorem of sets"?

> For any function of sets $f:A\to B$, define an equivalence relation on $A$ by
>   $$a_1\sim a_2\;\text{ when }\;f(a_1)=f(a_2)$$
>   Then $f$ factors through a surjection, a bijection, and an injection as follows:
>   $$\large A\; \xrightarrow[\text{surjective}]{\;\large a\;\mapsto\;[a]\;}\;A/{\sim}\; \xrightarrow[\text{bijective}]{\;\large [a]\;\mapsto\;f(a)\;} \;f(A)\;\xrightarrow[\text{injective}]{\;\large f(a)\;\mapsto\;f(a)\;}\;B$$

Comment: That's a really nice proof. In fact I learned by your post inclusion homomorphism and first isomorphism theorem for sets (easy to prove but seems really important). One point is that I couldn't prove that the composite map $B\xrightarrow{\large\;\;\text{inclusion}\;\;}AB\xrightarrow{\large\;\;\text{send }x\,\mapsto\, xA\;\;}AB/A$ without using the assumption $A\le N_G(B)$. So thank you very much for your post. You put effort on that and even on editing my question (sorry for writing $AB\backslash B$ instead of $AB/B$ don't know why did I do such thing).

Comment: @Scientifica: It may help to observe that given a group $G$ and subgroups $H,K\subseteq G$, neither of which are assumed to be normal, we have
$$HK=KH\iff HK\text{ is a subgroup of }G$$
Therefore in our situation, we have $AB=BA$, and it should be clear  why for any $x\in BA$, the coset $xA\in BA/A$ is equal to $yA\in BA/A$ for some $y\in B$. (This is why the composite map is surjective.)

Comment: Yes you're right! Forgot about that (Proposition 14 in the book). In fact we prove that $AB\le G$ in the theorem using $A\le N_G(B)$ but still I shouldn't forget the equivalence you stated. My bad! +1 for your comment :D