# Theorem 2.5.1 from Herstein's book

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-explanation

I am working out on the following theorem from Herstein's book and I have some question regarding its proof. Below I will upload the excerpt of this book: [image]

I have three questions:

1) Why are they considering the product in (1)? What does it give? I cannot understand the essence of that product.

2) The author writes the following "thus $hk$ is duplicated in the product **at least** $o(H\cap K)$ times". Why he wrote "at least" but not "exactly"?

3) What are they showing when they wrote $hk=h'k'$?

Would be very thankful for detailed answers to my questions.

Answer (score 3):

The argument shows the “double inequality”: when you take $x\in H\cap K$, then, for $h\in H$ and $k\in K$,
$$
hk=(hu)(u^{-1}k)
$$
This is (possibly), a different way of writing $hk$ as the product of an element in $H$ by an element in $K$.

Since $hu=hv$ only if $u=v$, we see that every element of $H\cap K$ provides a different way for writing $hk$ as a product of one element in $H$ by an element of $K$. Therefore there are *at least* $o(H\cap K)$ ways.

Then the author proves that the number of ways is *at most* $o(H\cap K)$; indeed, if $hk=h'k'$ is a rewriting, we get that $u=h^{-1}h'=k(k')^{-1}\in H\cap K$; then $hk=(hu)(u^{-1}k)$ is among the rewritings above. So we cannot have more rewritings than $o(H\cap K)$.

---

Maybe you can understand this better in terms of functions.

Consider the surjective map $f\colon H\times K\to HK$ defined by $f(h,k)=hk$. Define
$$
(h,k)\sim(h',k') \text{ if and only if }hk=h'k'
$$
Since $hk=h'k'$ is the same as $f(h,k)=f(h',k')$ this is an equivalence relation. We want to count the number of elements in $[(h,k)]_{\sim}$, the equivalence class of $(h,k)$.

Consider the map $g\colon H\cap K\to [(h,k)]_{\sim}$ defined by $g(u)=(hu,u^{-1}k)$, which is well defined because

1. $hu\in H$,
2. $u^{-1}k\in K$,
3. $(hu)(u^{-1}k)=hk$

We want to prove that this map is injective and surjective.

If $g(u)=g(v)$, then $hu=hv$ and so $u=v$. Hence $g$ is injective.

Let $(h',k')\in[(h,k)]_{\sim}$. Then $hk=h'k'$, so $u=h^{-1}h'=k(k')^{-1}\in H\cap K$ and
$$
(h',k')=(hu,u^{-1}k)=g(u)
$$
so $g$ is surjective. Hence $[(h,k)]_{\sim}$ has $o(H\cap K)$ elements. Since the cardinality is the same for all equivalence classes, we get that
$$
o(H\times K)=o(HK)o(H\cap K)
$$
because there are $o(HK)$ distinct equivalence classes.