# If $P,Q$ are $p-$subgroup of $G$, then so is $PQ$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group and $p$ divide $|G|$. Suppose $P$ and $Q$ are two subgroups s.t. $P\subset N_G(Q)$. Prove that $PQ$ is a $p-$subgroup of $G$.

I imagine that I have to use second isomorphism theorem, but I don't know how to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need second isomorphism theorem:

Recall that the equality always true $$|HK|=\dfrac{|H||K|}{|H\cap K|}.$$

In general $HK$ need not to be a subgroup. Just notice that $HK$ is a group if $K$ normalizes $H$, that is, when $K\leq N_G(H)$.

Comment: @Surb: It is an elementary fact and does not depend whether $HK$ is a subgroup or not. If you wish, I could write a proof for this fact.

Comment: @Surb: you can also check from this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/168942/order-of-a-product-of-subgroups-prove-that-ohk-fracohokoh-cap-k

Comment: Just to be sure : In this case, $PQ$ is a subgroup of $G$ right ? Because $PQ$ is a subgroup of $N_G(Q)$ (or not necessarily) (thanks for the link)

Comment: Yes, $PQ$ is a subgroup of $G$ in this case as $P$ normalize $Q$.

Comment: great. Thank you :) (and good answer too) (+1)

Comment: @Surb: you are welcme. What does "Je ne suis pas une pipe." realy mean?

Comment: It come from a peint of René Magritte "ceci n'est pas une pipe". I let you check on the internet :-)

Comment: @Surb I see right now :) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Your idea by using 2nd isomorphism theorem is the right idea. You have that $P$ is a subgroup of $N_G(Q)$. Since $Q\lhd N_G(Q)$ you have that $PQ\leq N_G(Q)$, and thus you can use 2nd isomorphism theorem in $N_G(Q)$.