# Number of k-combinations of an n-set using orbit-stabilizer theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, number-theory, group-actions

I have two similar questions:

Justify that a set of n elements has $\binom nk$ subsets of k elements by using the orbit-stabilizer theorem.

The orbit-stabilizer theorem says that $|Orb(x)|=[G:Stab(x)]=|G||Stab(x)|$

My attempt is if $X = \{1,2,3,...,n \} $ and S be the set of all subsets of X with k elements, then $S_{n}$ acts on $S$ with $n!$  permutations.

The orbit of $\{1,2,3, ...,k \}$ is S.

The order of the stabilizer should be $k!(n-k)!$(I do not know how to prove that!).

The second question:

For finite subgroups $H$ and $K$ of a group G, show that : $|HK| = \frac{|H||K|}{|H\cap K|}$ using the orbit-stabilizer theorem.

My attempt: with the direct product $H \times K$, we have $(h,k)*g := hgk^{-1}$.

Any idea on whether it is right or wrong.

Comment: The second question is covered at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/168942/order-of-a-product-of-subgroups-prove-that-ohk-fracohokoh-cap-k

Comment: Oh ... Many thanks

Comment: As for the first one, to find the order of the stabilizer you can try to prove that it is isomorphic to $S_k\times S_{n-k}$.