# Prove that a group that has more than one subgroup of order 5 must have order at least 25.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I know that my group would have to have an order divisible by 5 but I don't know the best way of solving this question. I first assumed I had two subgroups $$|H|\, and\,|K|\, with\,  order\, 5\, but\, H\, \neq K $$
I am not sure where to go after this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: for the *set* $HK$ we [have](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/168942/order-of-a-product-of-subgroups-prove-that-ohk-fracohokoh-cap-k) $|HK|=\frac{|H||K|}{|H \cap K|}$ and by Lagrange $H \cap K=1$.

Comment: Why would $$H \cap K = 1$$

Comment: $H \cap K$ is a subgroup of $H$ (and $K$). Hence its order divides $5$. If it is $5$ then $H \cap K=H$, which is equivalent to $H=K$.