# Let $H$ and $K$ be subgroups of finite order of group $G$ such that $|H|> \sqrt{|G|}$ and $|K|> \sqrt{|G|}$.Show that $|H \cap K|>1$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $H$ and $K$ be subgroups of finite order of group $G$ such that $|H|> \sqrt{|G|}$ and $|K|> \sqrt{|G|}$. Show that $|H \cap K|>1$.

Since $H$ and $K$ are subgroups of $G$. Hence $e\in H $ as well as $e\in K $(,where $e\in G$ is the identity element of $G$). So clearly  $e\in H\cap K$. Thus $|H\cap K |\geq 1$. But how to show, $|H\cap K |> 1$? I am not quite getting it. Also, there might be similar posts concerning the same topic on this site, but I can't seem to find it either . . .

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/168942/order-of-a-product-of-subgroups-prove-that-ohk-fracohokoh-cap-k. I believe this equality would be helpful.

Comment: Again: please work on your punctuation.

Answer (score 2):

We know that :$$\lvert G\rvert \geq \lvert HK \rvert=\frac{\lvert H \rvert \lvert K \rvert }{\lvert H\cap K\rvert }> \frac{\lvert G\rvert}{\lvert H\cap K\rvert}$$
So, $1>\frac{1}{\lvert H\cap K\rvert} \cdots $

Answer (score 0):

By Lagrange's theorem in a finite group, the order of a subgroup divides the order of the group.

Thus:
$|H|, |K|$ divide $|G|$

Now $e\in H\cap K\implies |H\cap K|\geq 1$.

Since $|H||K|>|G|$ by assumption:
let us take the right cosets of $S=H\cap K$

Index of a subgroup is defined $p=[G:S]=\frac{n}{m}$ and it is the number of right cosets of $S$.

Thus:
we have partition of $G$:

$\{Sg_1, Sg_2,...Sg_p\}, \{g_1,...g_p\}\in G$.

Where $n,m$ are the orders of $G,S$ respectively.

Now each coset of $H\cap K$ is also a coset of $H$ and a coset  of $K$.

So the indices of $H,K$ are smaller than $\frac{|G|}{\sqrt{|G|}}$.

This implies at least 2 cosets of $S$.
i.e.
$Se, Sg$, $e$ is the identity.

this implies $g\in S$.