# Order of double coset with group actions

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, alternative-proof, group-actions

This question is Question 10.20 of Abstract Algebra: A First Course by Dan Saracino.

Suppose $G$ is a group and $H<G$, $K<G$, and $g \in G$. Prove $HgK$ is the union of exactly $|H: H\cap gKg{-1}|$ of the left cosets of $K$ in $G$.

I know the usual proof:
$$|HgK|=|HgKg^{-1}g|=|HgKg^{-1}|=\frac{|H||gKg^{-1}|}{|H\cap gKg^{-1}|}=\frac{|H||K|}{|H\cap gKg^{-1}|}=[H: H\cap gKg{-1}]|K|$$

However, I want a proof using group action. Similar to the elegant proof of [Order of a product of subgroups. Prove that $o(HK) = \frac{o(H)o(K)}{o(H \cap K)}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/168942/order-of-a-product-of-subgroups-prove-that-ohk-fracohokoh-cap-k/168946#168946) by Martin Brandenburg.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$H$ acts on the set $G/K$ of cosets of $K$ in $G$ by left multiplication. The stabilizer of $gK$ is given by $H \cap gKg^{-1}$ and thus the orbit length is $[H:H\cap gKg^{-1}]$.